# Spring boot - replacing properties in Hadoop core-site.xml config file

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark, hadoop, spring-properties

I have Spring boot Spark based application with following Hadoop `core-site.xml` config file where I would like to replace the properties `${my.access.point.name}` and `${my.access.point.arn}` at runtime.

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.bucket.${my.access.point.name}.accesspoint.arn</name>
        <value>${my.access.point.arn}</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Here I have specified both of this properties in `application.properties` file and also, tried to pass it as environment variables from the `docker run` command.

It isn't doing the replacement and end up getting `Access Points usage is required but not configured for the bucket`.

Is there any other way to replace this properties at runtime?

At the moment, this file `core-site.xml` sits under `src/main/resources/`.
Is there anyway I specify this file from external location as an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, you can get or create a custom Configuration instance.

For Spark, hadoopConfiguration is part of the SparkContext